# Guessing game woes

Tags: javascript, random, numbers

Hello i am very new to javascript and have been trying to make a random number guessing game. I think i almost got it except there is one thing i cant figure out. Everytime i run it i have to type in my number twice and it also only returns Lower no matter what number i type in.

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

print("I have thought of a random number in the range of 1 to 100. Guess!");
{ 
    while (randomNumber != readline())
        if (readline() < randomNumber) 
        {
            print("Lower");
        } 
        else if (readline() > randomNumber) 
        {
            print("Higher");
        } 
        else if (readline() == randomNumber) 
        {
            print("Good Job");
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to format your code so that it easier to see what is going on. For some reason you have put braces around your while statement. This will still work, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: For every comparison that you do you are reading a new line? I guess that for every input you want to do 3 comparisons, don't you?

Comment: Logan - Please stop editing your question and destroying the formatting!

Comment: You might try posting what JavaScript interpreter you're using too. `readline` is not part of a typical browser implementation. I assume this is node.js or spidermonkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is you are calling `readline` multiple times per iteration of your while loop. Here I have stored the value of `readline` into a variable and use that to test:

```
var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

print("I have thought of a random number in the range of 1 to 100. Guess!");

var hasGuessedCorrectly = false;

while (!hasGuessedCorrectly) 
{
    var guess = readline();
    if (guess < randomNumber) 
    {
        print("Lower");
    } 
    else if (guess > randomNumber) 
    {
        print("Higher");
    } 
    else if (guess == randomNumber) 
    {
        print("Good Job");
        hasGuessedCorrectly = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah ok i see thanks. Its alot cleaner now. As i said im really new to java script XD. LOL also i jsut realized i had my greater than and less thans switched. Also im new to this site i couldnt figure out the whole editing my question thing. Were you guys editing it for me?

Comment: Also, "alot" isn't a word ;-)

Comment: @LoganDodd - yes, your code was badly formatted,so I reformatted. Learn to format your code now as it will make it much clearer what is going on.